# HTML5/CSS3 horizontal list

Tags: html, list, css, html-lists

So I'm doing a big project just for fun, but there's a problem with my lists. When I got everything set up, but the list items nest themselves within the parent border, instead of opening fully to the right in its own border. I've tried padding each one, and setting margins, but it doesn't solve the problem. Below is a small portion of the code. If you can provide any answers, that'd be great.

```
 <html>
<head>
A Song Of Ice And Fire
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
</head>
<body>
<ul id="Houses">
<li id="Dorne"><a href="Dorne.html">Dorne</a>
<ul id="H1">
<li id="DGH">Great House:
<ul id="DGH1">
<li id="Martell"><a href="Martell.html">Martell</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="DKH">Knight House:
<ul id="DKH1">
<li id="Dalt"><a href="Dalt.html">Dalt</a></li>
<li id="DHH"><a href="Dayne_of_High_Hermitage.html">Dayne of High Hermitage</a></li>
<li id="Drwr"><a href="Drinkwater.html">Drinkwater</a></li>
<li id="Sangar"><a href="Santagar.html">Santagar</a></li>
<li id="Wells"><a href="Wells.html">Wells</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="DNH">Noble House:
<ul id="DNH1">
<li id="Ally"><a href="Allyrion.html">Allyrion</a></li>
<li id="Bmont"><a href="Blackmont.html">Blackmont</a></li>
<li id="DS"><a href="Dayne_of_Starfall.html">Dayne of Starfall</a></li>
<li id="Fowler"><a href="Fowler.html">Fowler</a></li>
<li id="Garg"><a href="Gargalen.html">Gargalen</a></li>
<li id="Jord"><a href="Jordayne.html">Jordayne</a></li>
<li id="Ladyb"><a href="Ladybright.html">Ladybright</a></li>
<li id="Manw"><a href="Manwoody.html">Manwoody</a></li>
<li id="Qorgyle"><a href="Qorgyle.html">Qorgyle</a></li>
<li id="Toland"><a href="Toland.html">Toland</a></li>
<li id="Uller"><a href="Uller.html">Uller</a></li>
<li id="Vaith"><a href="Vaith.html">Vaith</a></li>
<li id="Wyl"><a href="Wyl.html">Wyl</a></li>
<li id="Yron"><a href="Yronwood.html">Yronwood</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 /*Nav Menu*/
#Houses{list-style-type:none;}

/*Dorne*/
#Houses #Dorne{list-style-type:none; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DGH{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DGH #DGH1{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DGH #DGH1 #Martell{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 {list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH {list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH #DKH1{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH #DKH1 #Dalt{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH #DKH1 #DHH{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH #DKH1 #Drwr{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH #DKH1 #Sangar{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH #DKH1 #Wells{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 {list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Ally{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Bmont{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #DS{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Fowler{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Garg{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Jord{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Ladyb{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Manw{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Qorgyle{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Toland{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Uller{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Vaith{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Wyl{list-style-type:none;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1 #Yron{list-style-type:none;}

#Houses #Dorne #H1{display:none;}
#Houses #Dorne:hover #H1{display:inline-block; visibility:visible;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DGH #DGH1{display:none;} 
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DGH:hover #DGH1{display:inline-block; visibility:visible;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH #DKH1{display:none;} 
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH:hover #DKH1{display:inline-block; visibility:visible;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1{display:none;} 
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH:hover #DNH1{display:inline-block; visibility:visible;}

#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DGH{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DGH> #DGH1> #Martell{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DKH{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DKH> #DKH1> #Dalt{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DKH> #DKH1> #DHH{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DKH> #DKH1> #Drwr{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DKH> #DKH1> #Sangar{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DKH> #DKH1> #Wells{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Ally{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Bmont{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #DS{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Fowler{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Garg{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Jord{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Ladyb{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Manw{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Qorgyle{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Toland{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Uller{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Vaith{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Wyl{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DNH> #DNH1> #Yron{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Houses #Dorne #H1{list-style-type:none;margin-left:30px;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DKH #DKH1{list-style-type:none;margin-left:30px;}
#Houses #Dorne #H1 #DNH #DNH1{list-style-type:none;margin-left:30px;}
#Houses> #Dorne> #H1> #DGH> #DGH1> #Martell{display:block; border-style:solid; width: 70px;margin-left:30px;}
```